# Python offset column value with previous record value if the record meets a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm brand new to Python and am stuck on how to conditionally offset values. I've successfully been able to use the shift function when I just need to create a new column. However, this doesn't seem to work with a function.

Original df:

```
BEGIN   SPEED   SPEED_END
322     28      0
341     0       23
496     5       1
500     0       0
775     0       0
979     0       0
1015    0       0
1022    0       14
1050    11      6
```

I want the `BEGIN` value to be changed to the previous record `BEGIN` value and the `SPEED` value to be changed to the previous record `SPEED` value on records where `SPEED=0` and the previous `SPEED_END=0`.

So the table above should be:

```
BEGIN   SPEED   SPEED_END
322     28      0
322     28      23
496     5       1
500     0       0
500     0       0
500     0       0
500     0       0
500     0       14
1050    11      6
```

I've tried a lot of different things. Currently, I've tried:

```
def cont(row,param):
    if row['SPEED'] == 0 and row['SPEED_END'].shift(1) == 0:
        val = row[param].shift(1)
    else:
        val = row[param]
    return val

df['BEGIN'] = df.apply(cont, param='BEGIN', axis=1)
```

But this gives me the error:

> AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'shift'", u'occurred at index 0')

Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
begin_cond = (df['SPEED'] == 0) & (df['SPEED_END'].shift(1) == 0)
df['BEGIN'] = df['BEGIN'].mask(begin_cond).ffill().astype(int)
```

Essentially, `mask` will replace the values in `df['BEGIN']` where `begin_cond` is `True` with `NaN`.  Then, `ffill` will forward fill the `NaN` values with the last valid value in `df['BEGIN']`.

The resulting output:

```
   BEGIN  SPEED  SPEED_END
0    322     28          0
1    322      0         23
2    496      5          1
3    500      0          0
4    500      0          0
5    500      0          0
6    500      0          0
7    500      0         14
8   1050     11          6
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to working! I added some more details and rows of data to my original post. I need it to loop through and if it changes the BEGIN and then if the next record also meets the same condition then update that BEGIN to be the previously updated BEGIN. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a two-step solution that will SHOCK you.

```
df['begin_temp'] = df.begin.shift(1)
df['begin_shifted'] = df.ix[( df.SPEED== 0)  | (df.SPEED_END== 0), 'begin_temp']
```

and then

```
df.ix[df.begin_shifted.isnull(),'begin_shifted'] = df.ix[df.begin_shifted.isnull(),'begin']
```